# How to use the method to show localstream in videoview in WEBRTC latest framework <Anakros/WebRTC>? - for webrtc framework(iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, webrtc, video-capture, apprtc

After updating the webrtc framework for the latest one , I am not getting how to show local stream to user cause methodology is changed which has no sample on repository's "iOS" folder.

in old code...

```
   RTCVideoCapturer *capturer = [RTCVideoCapturer capturerWithDeviceName:cameraID];
   RTCMediaConstraints *mediaConstraints = [self defaultMediaStreamConstraints];
   RTCVideoSource *videoSource = [_factory videoSourceWithCapturer:capturer constraints:mediaConstraints];
   localVideoTrack = [_factory videoTrackWithID:@"ARDAMSv0" source:videoSource];
```

The RTCVideoCapturer object and RTCVideoSource object was linked here to each other.

But in new code...

```
  RTCVideoSource *source = [_factory videoSource];
  RTCCameraVideoCapturer *capturer = [[RTCCameraVideoCapturer alloc] initWithDelegate:source];
  [_delegate appClient:self didCreateLocalCapturer:capturer];
    localVideoTrack = [_factory videoTrackWithSource:source
                                             trackId:kARDVideoTrackId];
```

There is no connection to each other.
So, the delegate method does what ,
[_delegate appClient:self didCreateLocalCapturer:capturer];
I am not getting it. [Help Required!]

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem. I'm stuck with the same thing

Comment: Yes @WorieN I solved this.... posting answer of this question in a while...

Comment: @WorieN posted the answer ! please upvote if you find this helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement this delegate method in video call view controller....

```
- (void)appClient:(ARDAppClient *)client didCreateLocalCapturer:(RTCCameraVideoCapturer *)localCapturer{

    NSLog(@"%s %@",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__ ,localCapturer);

    _captureController =  [[ARDCaptureController alloc] initWithCapturer:localCapturer
                                                                settings:[[ARDSettingsModel alloc] init]];
    [_captureController startCapture];
}
```

Then.... this method calls it to create the same...

```
 - (RTCVideoTrack *)createLocalVideoTrack {
      RTCVideoTrack* localVideoTrack = nil;
      // The iOS simulator doesn't provide any sort of camera capture
      // trying to open a local stream.
    #if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
      if (![_settings currentAudioOnlySettingFromStore]) {
          RTCVideoSource *source = [_factory videoSource];
          RTCCameraVideoCapturer *capturer = [[RTCCameraVideoCapturer alloc] initWithDelegate:source];
          [_delegate appClient:self didCreateLocalCapturer:capturer];
          localVideoTrack = [_factory videoTrackWithSource:source
                                                   trackId:kARDVideoTrackId];

          [_delegate appClient:self didReceiveLocalVideoTrack:localVideoTrack];

      }
```

Then call ...

```
_localVideoTrack = [self createLocalVideoTrack];
```

in your init method...

```
- (void)initCall {
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    if (!_isTurnComplete) {
        return;
    }
    self.state = kARDAppClientStateConnected;
    _localVideoTrack = [self createLocalVideoTrack];
    // Create peer connection.
    _constraints = [self defaultPeerConnectionConstraints];

}
```

This code does me able to achieve this!

Comment: And could you please share the code that help to render the videotrack to RTCEAGLVideoView? I do not know why, but I have no video there. Maybe you store RTCEAGLVideoView in some VideoView that helps to render it?

Comment: I subclass my video view with RTCEAGLVideoView and identified each with caller user id , and also you have to assign delegate as self. No idea exactly what problem you are facing ... I told as much a could understand with your comment. @WorieN